# Nested loop optmization in JSP and Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, spring, jsp, optimization, nested-loops

I am returning three maps from my SPRING controller. Then all the three maps are iterated on jsp page using angular js. The code that I am using is:

```
<td ng-repeat="x in response.skillList" title='Resource Name: {{y.name}}, Skill: {{x.skillCode}}'>
<span ng-repeat="a in response.assessmentList">
<div ng-switch on="switchHelper(y.userid+'_'+x.skillId, a.matrixCellId)">
<div ng-switch-when="1">{{a.assessmentValue}} ({{a.interpretation}}</div>
</div>
</span>
```

There are always more than 100 records in "x" and 10 records for "y". There may or may not be some value in "a" according to "x" and "y".

The main problem is that the nested loop takes so much time and the browser almost hangs.

Comment: What exactly you want ? Do u want to update the logic or want to cache data ..

Comment: I want to update the logic. Nested loops takes too much time to display the information. In any way either by caching or by upating the logic I want to make the result displayed fast.

Comment: logic will depends on your project requirement and for caching , you can go for localstorge or indexeddb for offline caching also if these data wont change frequently , you can also use cache: true in your http calll while getting data.

Comment: If you want your form load more faster , try minification of all ur angular js related stuff like controller, service, constant, css. using gruntjs / Nodejs..hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way where I can check before going into the third nested loop to check whether there is some element with given key, e.g if exists("key in x"+"key in y") in the "a", then only go for "a in reponse.data", otherwise  not?

Comment: pls check  ng-if or ng-show if it helps